# How should I track backend progress with cpu usage of Ajax call Jquery?

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, laravel, artificial-intelligence

I am using Ajax Calls to call 1 AI Model rest API through the front end. So REST API backend is using Python/ai for processing.

While I call that Ajax request, I want to **progress and GPU usage in real-time** so the frontend user can have an exact idea of ongoing progress.

Does anyone have any idea how can I achieve this?

Comment: You're asking how to get a progress bar related to some undefined amount of time an AI needs to perform a task? I'm not sure about what AI API are you using, and if it can provide a median progress value depending on the query, token. Regarding GPU... well you might need to attach to the header or to the responses the GPU-Usage value somehow, or create a separate WebSocket communication layer that provides real-time usage.